# Microsoft Report Viewer only partially displays

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, microsoft-reporting

Microsoft Report Viewer is only displaying three fields, two of which are disabled. It should be displaying a large, fully functional report.

The sql server configuration has been vetted for by somebody who has done it many times and is running these same reports in a production environment. We've also scoured the web.config and haven't found anything out of place.

[Here's an image of what the (broken) report looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh1Wx.jpg) The "End Date" and the "Stores" fields are disabled. Clicking View Report brings up the loading spinner, which then closes without changing anything or throwing errors.

We are seeing this problem on two different QA environments, one using old ASP.NET and one using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Web.config highlights

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=-------;" timeout="30" />

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>

<pages enableViewState="true" clientIDMode="AutoID">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="rsweb" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </controls>
</pages>

<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <handlers>      
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Here are the relevant parts of the web page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID='scriptManager' runat='server' AsyncPostBackTimeout="1800" EnablePartialRendering="false" />

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" OnReportError="ReportError"
  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="685px" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="985px"
  InternalBorderColor="White" InternalBorderWidth="0px" BackColor="White">
  <ServerReport />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

We are at a loss for ideas. Has anybody seen anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reports were misconfigured after all. Thanks for the responses, though!

Comment: to clarify, did the reports run from the standard RS portal, or did they fail there as well?... if they ran in the Portal, what about the reports was misconfigured?... seeing similar but we've proven the report runs fine in the portal so presumably not report / RS side.

Answer (score 0):

The report viewer control relies on postbacks which don't exist out of the box in an MVC app if you are using routing.

I also see you are using script manager why is that referenced if you are not using an UpdatePanel. Anyway, the timeout may be less than the report allows and you are seeing client timeouts or client disconnected errors.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that same problem where i attached RS to my MVC Application and i got the solution (Web Browser Compatibility).

What i did is just, to add meta tag on my header portion of my form.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;IE=EmulateIE8;"/>
```

Best Regards